# Blurry/Pixelated Images on mobile phone

Tags: android, css, webkit

In my phonegap app I display a 240x240 image in a listview where it is resized to 80x80. This works fine and the image is crisp:

[image: Crisp]

However, somewhere else in my app I want to display those images too. Since I want to display a whole lot more of them, I am using sprites. Still, the sprite element (that one image within the sprite) is 240x240 and gets resized to 80x80 again (with `background-size`), but now it looks like this:

[image: Blurry]

If I use a smaller size (like 120x120 or 80x80) and resize it to 80x80, it is not pixelated, but extremely blurry. The only difference to the first case described is using CSS sprites, but so many use them, I can't imagine this to be a problem. Does anyone have an idea what might cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incidentally I found the source of the problem: `z-index`.

The images are drawn as background images on `div` elements that live within a wrapping `div`. If I give them a `z-index` to ensure that they're on top, they get blurry. Removing the `z-index` causes them to be rendered perfectly.

Could this actually be a bug in the Webkit engine?

Comment: This was definitely it. I could fix it now by wrapping the `div`s into a second wrapper and giving the `z-index` to this one.

Comment: So strange, I'm having a very similar issue but with fonts imported with @font-face. They look fine everywhere in the site, except when in a modal with a z-index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Paint, confirm the following before using paint instance:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Comment: This sounds like native code. My app is written in HTML5/CSS with Phonegap.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target- 
densityDpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum- 
scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>  -use target-densityDpi=device-dpi if not using. Use different images for different device densities.

Comment: I am using different sprites depending on the device resolution/density (hence the problems). Using `target-densityDpi` does make it look good, but unfortunately the rest of the app is super small then (even the jQM stuff). Plus I still don't know why in one situation the image looks fine and in the other one it doesn't.

Comment: I have also just read that `target-densitydpi` is removed from WebKit, so it is deprecated. I am already using `window.devicePixelRatio` for picking the proper sprite size, by the way. As stated above, it has to work somehow since other pictures look just fine too. I'd really not like to switch from sprites to images, though -- that'd be sort of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `border-radius: 1%;` fixed this for me